# GridView Control with different child categories that have no relationship to each other

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I may be missing something here so I apologise if this question may come across as obvious.
In a XAML WinRT app, I can have a GridView control that I can throw a collection of stuff at, and then using DataTemplates etc I can render that stuff on screen.

How can I take this a step further and have a single “master” GridView control which contains several sections which get their data from different places and exist within the app as different collections of stuff?

For example, take the built in Games app. Here we have different sections – Spotlight, Friends, Game Activity etc which are all very different from each other, have different data and are displayed in different ways but they all exist within the same GridView control.

How can this be done?

I do hope this makes sense

Kris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you want to have a group of groups, and display each of the child groups using different templates.

The way I did it was to derive all the child items from a common base class (or you could build a group of groups of Objects, I suppose).  Then we used the DataTemplateSelector to pick the appropriate template for each item in the master GridView.

We had to go a step or two further than that in practice, but that's the theory behind how I achieved a similar goal.